# PHP strcmp function in usort not sorting alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting, strcmp, usort

I have this script

```
$todos=array(
    '0' => array('id' => 46, 'nombre' => 'b2 miami downtown','precio' => 149.01,'tipo' => 'expedia'),
    '1' => array('id' => 242,'nombre' => 'b2 Miami Downtown','precio' => 176.98,'tipo' => 'hotelbeds'),
    '2' => array('id' => 240,'nombre' => 'b2 Miami Downtown','precio' => 131.62,'tipo' => 'hotelbeds'),
    '3' => array('id' => 241,'nombre' => 'b2 Miami Downtown','precio' => 131.62,'tipo' => 'hotelbeds'),
    '4' => array( 'id' => 178,'nombre' => 'Z Ocean Hotel South Beach','precio' => 400.93,'tipo' => 'expedia'),
    '5' => array( 'id' => 254,'nombre' => 'Whitelaw Hotel','precio' => 142.29,'tipo' => 'hotelbeds'),
    '6' => array( 'id' => 124, 'nombre' => 'Whitelaw Hotel','precio' => 132.04,'tipo' => 'tourico'),
    '7' => array( 'id' => 62, 'nombre' => 'Westin Colonnade Coral Gables','precio' => 138.39,'tipo' => 'tourico'),
    '8' => array( 'id' => 275, 'nombre' => 'Westgate South Beach','precio' => 166.79,'tipo' => 'hotelbeds'),
    '9' => array( 'id' => 44, 'nombre' => 'W South Beach','precio' => 374.55,'tipo' => 'tourico'),
    '10' => array( 'id' => 206, 'nombre' => 'Holiday Inn Express West Doral Miami Airport','precio' => 103.22,'tipo' => 'hotelbeds'),
    '11' => array( 'id' => 117, 'nombre' => 'Holiday Inn Express Miami International Airport','precio' => 106.3,'tipo' => 'expedia'),
    '12' => array( 'id' => 114, 'nombre' => 'Holiday Inn Express Miami Airport Doral Area','precio' => 113,'tipo' => 'tourico'),
    '13' => array( 'id' => 78, 'nombre' => 'Holiday Inn Express Doral','precio' => 93.36,'tipo' => 'expedia'),
    '14' => array( 'id' => 62, 'nombre' => 'Holiday Inn Express & Suites Kendall East Miami','precio' => 128.46,'tipo' => 'expedia'),
    '15' => array( 'id' => 18, 'nombre' => 'Best Western Plus Kendall Hotel & Suites','precio' => 429.55,'tipo' => 'tourico'),
    '16' => array( 'id' => 19, 'nombre' => 'Best Western Plus Kendall Hotel & Suites','precio' => 429.55,'tipo' => 'expedia'),
    '17' => array( 'id' => 120, 'nombre' => 'Best Western Kendall Hotel & Suites','precio' => 114.27,'tipo' => 'expedia'),
    '18' => array( 'id' => 69, 'nombre' => 'Holiday Inn Express & Suites Kendall','precio' => 126.5,'tipo' => 'expedia'));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($todos);

    function comp($a,$b){
        if(soundex($a['nombre'])==soundex($b['nombre'])) return($a['precio']-$b['precio']);
        if(soundex($a['nombre'])!=soundex($b['nombre'])) return strcmp($a['nombre'], $b['nombre']);
    }
    usort($todos,'comp');
    print_r($todos);
    echo "<pre>";
```

I need to sort the array, first by hotel name, and after that each hotel by price (precio).
The reason to use **soundex**, is because the same hotel may have a diferent name depending on the provider (proveedor), so I need to agroup the hotels, and put first the lowest price, to delete the others so I can offer only the best price.

The output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [nombre] => b2 miami downtown
            [precio] => 149.01
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 242
            [nombre] => b2 Miami Downtown
            [precio] => 176.98
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 240
            [nombre] => b2 Miami Downtown
            [precio] => 131.62
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 241
            [nombre] => b2 Miami Downtown
            [precio] => 131.62
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 178
            [nombre] => Z Ocean Hotel South Beach
            [precio] => 400.93
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 254
            [nombre] => Whitelaw Hotel
            [precio] => 142.29
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 124
            [nombre] => Whitelaw Hotel
            [precio] => 132.04
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [nombre] => Westin Colonnade Coral Gables
            [precio] => 138.39
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 275
            [nombre] => Westgate South Beach
            [precio] => 166.79
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [nombre] => W South Beach
            [precio] => 374.55
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express West Doral Miami Airport
            [precio] => 103.22
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 117
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express Miami International Airport
            [precio] => 106.3
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 114
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express Miami Airport Doral Area
            [precio] => 113
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 78
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express Doral
            [precio] => 93.36
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express & Suites Kendall East Miami
            [precio] => 128.46
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [nombre] => Best Western Plus Kendall Hotel & Suites
            [precio] => 429.55
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [nombre] => Best Western Plus Kendall Hotel & Suites
            [precio] => 429.55
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 120
            [nombre] => Best Western Kendall Hotel & Suites
            [precio] => 114.27
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 69
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express & Suites Kendall
            [precio] => 126.5
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

)
```

**THE SORTED ARRAY**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 120
            [nombre] => Best Western Kendall Hotel & Suites
            [precio] => 114.27
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [nombre] => Best Western Plus Kendall Hotel & Suites
            [precio] => 429.55
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [nombre] => Best Western Plus Kendall Hotel & Suites
            [precio] => 429.55
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 78
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express Doral
            [precio] => 93.36
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express West Doral Miami Airport
            [precio] => 103.22
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 117
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express Miami International Airport
            [precio] => 106.3
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 114
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express Miami Airport Doral Area
            [precio] => 113
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 69
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express & Suites Kendall
            [precio] => 126.5
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [nombre] => Holiday Inn Express & Suites Kendall East Miami
            [precio] => 128.46
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [nombre] => W South Beach
            [precio] => 374.55
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 275
            [nombre] => Westgate South Beach
            [precio] => 166.79
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [nombre] => Westin Colonnade Coral Gables
            [precio] => 138.39
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 124
            [nombre] => Whitelaw Hotel
            [precio] => 132.04
            [tipo] => tourico
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 254
            [nombre] => Whitelaw Hotel
            [precio] => 142.29
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 178
            [nombre] => Z Ocean Hotel South Beach
            [precio] => 400.93
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 240
            [nombre] => b2 Miami Downtown
            [precio] => 131.62
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 241
            [nombre] => b2 Miami Downtown
            [precio] => 131.62
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [nombre] => b2 miami downtown
            [precio] => 149.01
            [tipo] => expedia
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 242
            [nombre] => b2 Miami Downtown
            [precio] => 176.98
            [tipo] => hotelbeds
        )

)
```

As you see "b2 Miami Downtown" should be in the top of the array not last.

Please help with this.

Thanks!!!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP manual for [strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php):

> Note that this comparison is case sensitive.

Letters A-Z come *before* letters a-z. Try [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) instead.

**EDIT:** even if using strcasecmp, be aware that its case-insensitiveness only really applies to the English charset. If you use names in other locales (Spanish, French, German, you name it), those non-basic-ASCII characters will still be compared in a binary way. E.g.,

`posada el Ñandú rengo` is not equivalent to `posada el ñandÚ rengo`.

You may want to use [multibyte string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions such as mb_convert_case or mb_strtolower before comparing.